# Ionic Soap Service with Credentials

Tags: jquery, angularjs, soap, ionic-framework

Following this [tutorial](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap)

I am trying to access my Soap web service which has username and password requirement.

```
.factory(“HHService”, [‘$soap’, function ($soap) {
    var base_url = “My Url”;

    $soap.setCredentials(“username”, “Password”);
    return {
        SaveResultQuery: function (EmailAddress, ) {
            return $soap.post(base_url, “UpdateStatsSOAP”, { EmailAddress: EmailAddress });
        }
    }
}])
```

Thats the factory and then I invoke it like this for getting the result:

```
HHService.SaveResultQuery($rootScope.Email).then(function (data) {
    debugger
});
```

This opens up popup on app for Username and password. Can you please guide where am I am wrong ad what are the alternatives of this?

I have also Tried with jQuery and of course the Cross origin kicks in.
Any help will be appreciated.